# Angular directive for country/regions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm kind of new to Angular so I apologize if this is simple.

I have a working app that has multiple places where the user must first select a country from a list of countries and then a region from a select.  I already have the list of countries and the list of regions for each country.  The region selector becomes a plain textbox if the system doesn't have any regions for the selected country.

It works well, but I've got like 8 different places where I need this functionality.  For example, the app asks for both birth place and death place.

It seems like I should put this functionality into a directive, but all the examples I find are either passing in a single field from the model (ie. ng-model='country') or the entire scope object.  I need to pass in the specific country and region fields of the model for each instance of the directive.

How do I do that?

Here is an example of what I have now.  How can I turn this into a single 'country/region selector' directive so I can reuse it instead of basically copying and pasting this all over the place.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birth_country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Birth Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select id="birth_country" ng-model="person.birth_country" ng-options="country.text as country.text for country in country_options" class="form-control" ng-change="getBirthRegions(person.birth_country)" ></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birth_region" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Birth State/Region</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="birth_region" type="text" ng-model="person.birth_region" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the birth state/region" ng-hide="birth_region_options.length > 0" />
        <select id="birth_region" ng-model="person.birth_region" ng-options="region.text as region.text for region in birth_region_options" class="form-control" ng-show="birth_region_options.length > 0"></select>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="death_country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Death Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select id="death_country" ng-model="person.death_country" ng-options="country.text as country.text for country in country_options" class="form-control" ng-change="getDeathRegions(person.death_country)" ></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="death_region" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Death State/Region</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="death_region" type="text" ng-model="person.death_region" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the death state/region" ng-hide="death_region_options.length > 0" />
        <select id="death_region" ng-model="person.death_region" ng-options="region.text as region.text for region in death_region_options" class="form-control" ng-show="death_region_options.length > 0"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your single field you pass in can be a JavaScript Object.

So all you have to do is use something like `ng-model="addressLocation.country"` and `ng-model="addressLocation.region"` on your input.

Then use that single object in your directive: `my-directive="addressLocation"`

**EDIT:**

To answer your edited question about creating the actual directive, it looks like you need to read up on how to create directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

What you're going to want to do is create a directive which you probably want to use as an element, possibly move your template HTML into an external HTML file and use `templateUrl` in the directive, and use an isolated scope with (possibly) multiple variables on it.

An example:

```
.directive('countryRegionSelector', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=', 
            label: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'country-region-selector.html', //This contains your HTML
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('model.country', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                 //Your get____Regions() here
            }
            scope.country_options = [...];
            scope.region_options = [];
        }
    }
});
```

The template will look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country-{{label}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}} Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select id="country-{{label}}" ng-model="model.country" ng-options="country.text as country.text for country in country_options" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="region-{{label}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}} State/Region</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="region-{{label}}" type="text" ng-model="model.region" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the birth state/region" ng-hide="region_options.length > 0" />
        <select id="region-{{label}}" ng-model="model.region" ng-options="region.text as region.text for region in region_options" class="form-control" ng-show="region_options.length > 0"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use it something like this:

```
<country-region-selector model="person.birth" label="Birth">
<country-region-selector model="person.death" label="Death">
```

**Note:** This hasn't been tested, just written off the top of my head for now as a general template you can use

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects to a directive if you declare a scope in it. In my example directive a list of countries and the object for selecting a country and a region can be passed in. So when you use the directive you just pass in the values of the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="Origin as originCtrl">
  <p>Selected country: {{ originCtrl.selected.country }}</p>
  <div select-origin countries="originCtrl.countries" selected="originCtrl.selected"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can just add a select for the regions and put your getRegions function into a service which you can inject into the directive.

```
angular.module('application', [])
  .controller('Origin', function($scope) {
    this.countries = ['France', 'Russia', 'China'];

    this.selected = {
      country: null,
      region: null
   }
 })
 .directive('selectOrigin', function(){
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      countries: '=',
      selected: '='
    },
    template: '<select ng-options="country for country in countries" 
               ng-model="selected.country"></select>'
   };
 });
```

Also here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pxwXMmxFgNB2w55E1Y1V?p=preview)